# brave update error

Tags: updates, update-manager

trying to update my system and I'm getting an error update.
How can I fix ? Thanks

```
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com xenial InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1555193394  KEYEXPIRED 1555193433  KEYEXPIRED 1555193433  KEYEXPIRED 1555193394  KEYEXPIRED 1555193433  KEYEXPIRED 1555193394  KEYEXPIRED 1555193433
W: Failed to fetch https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/dists/xenial/InRelease  The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1555193394  KEYEXPIRED 1555193433  KEYEXPIRED 1555193433  KEYEXPIRED 1555193394  KEYEXPIRED 1555193433  KEYEXPIRED 1555193394  KEYEXPIRED 1555193433
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 1):

I used

```
curl -s https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/brave-core.asc | sudo apt-key --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/brave-browser-release.gpg add -

source /etc/os-release

echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/ $UBUNTU_CODENAME main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release-${UBUNTU_CODENAME}.list

sudo apt update

sudo apt install brave-keyring brave-browser
```

and now it seems to be fine...

[Source](https://brave-browser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-brave.html#linux)